# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 - can't perform any action [user doesn't have permission]

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, permission-denied

Suddenly my SQL Server Management Studio 18 is not working properly. I can't create any db or access old db.

I tried doing this

1. Log in as Administrator on my PC
2. Log in SQL Server Management Studio as "Windows Authentication"
3. Click Security > Login > choose login where I want to create DB > right click then Properties > click server roles > then checklist 'dbcreator'.

But then when I click on 'OK' I got error "User do not have permission to perform this action".

I tried some more solution but i couldn't save any change, always get same error.

please help. I am stuck so badly.

Comment: Administrator of the PC is not necessary an admin of the Sql server.  Try  Sql Server authentication, connect as sa.

Comment: This won't "suddenly" happen, this means that *someone* revoked the permissions of the `LOGIN`/`USER` or removed it from the relevant roles. It's also not SSMS that isn't "not working properly", SSMS is just an IDE, it's the SQL Server instance you're connected to that is telling you you don't have the permissions. If you just installed SQl Server, it seems like you haven't set up the instance to have your Windows Account as a `sysadmin`, or priviledged enough after it was installed by using the `sa` account.